# There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper

Tags: windows-server-2008, rpc

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter part of a domain. The DebugView constantly spits out this error:

```
[5592] 5592: 2014-01-08 13:32:39.410 [DirectResult] Error (Id=0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706D9): There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706D9)
```

I've gone through the recommendations from [Replication error 1753 There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/replication-error-1753-there-are-no-more-endpoints-available-from-the-endpoint-mapper%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) but wasn't able to fix the issue or pinpoint the main cause.

Other approaches taken without a positive result:

- restarted the system
- restarted the DNS server

Any idea of what to look for and what's causing this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Snippet from DebugView containing the same PID [5592]:

```
[5592] 5592: 2014-01-09 13:07:58.788 [DirectResult] Error (Id=0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706D9): There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706D9) 
[5592]    at Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.NativeMethods.INetFwPolicy2.IsRuleGroupCurrentlyEnabled(String group) 
[5592]    at Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.DirectResult.GetRemoteManagementEnabled() 
[5592] 5592: 2014-01-09 13:08:52.735 [CBS]                       IsCacheStillGood: True. 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] Buffer insufficient for RenderEvent for LiteRecord, Retrying with the correct buffer-122-The data area passed to a system call is too small 
[5592] 5592: 2014-01-09 13:08:55.380 [Virtualization]            Search scope = \\FENDERVMM\root\virtualization, search query = SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem WHERE NOT Name='FENDERVMM' 
[5592] 5592: 2014-01-09 13:08:55.390 [Virtualization]            End DetectVirtualMachines, 0 virtual machines detected 
[5592] 5592: 2014-01-09 13:08:58.991 [DirectResult] Error (Id=0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706D9): There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706D9) 
[5592]    at Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.NativeMethods.INetFwPolicy2.IsRuleGroupCurrentlyEnabled(String group) 
[5592]    at Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.DirectResult.GetRemoteManagementEnabled()
```

Comment: Is that the only line for pid `[5592]`? Please post the rest of the stack if possible

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen After digging through my old notes I've found the logs that you've asked for. Besides the same PID, would you like to see anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the error itself doesn't seem to make much sense, it seems to be a [symptom of an unavailable Firewall Service](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13ce9c14-53a1-491e-98c1-595cdc5208ce/directresult-error-id0-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x800706d9-there-are-no?forum=ilm2).

If you have disabled the Windows Firewall service, simply enable it again.

I would recommend configuring the ruleset properly, but if it's a requirement to bypass the builtin firewall on the server, simply turn it off for all applicable profiles:

### Using the Firewall console:

1. Open the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security console (`wf.msc`)
2. Right-click the "Windows Firewall..." node in the tree view on the left
3. Select Properties
4. Switch to the tab corresponding to the profile you want to configure.
5. Change the "Firewall State" setting to "Off"

### Using Control Panel:

1. Open the Firewall control panel item (`firewall.cpl`)
2. Click "Turn Windows Firewall on or off"
3. Turn off the firewall for the current or all profiles